# Plotting Lists in Matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

I have to lists of that kind (series and pred_upd):

[image]

I try to put them together on a plot doing that:

```
az = series.plot(figsize=(12,8), label='o')
ax = pred_upd.plot(style='r--', label='Dynamic Prediction');
ax.legend();
az.legend();
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

I receive error:

```
-> 2417         if isinstance(data, DataFrame):
   2418             if x is not None:
   2419                 if com.is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html), I think you are using it incorrectly. I cannot really infer what `type` are the variables `series` and `pred_upd` are, but I am assuming they are of type `list` (from your example).

To use matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(series)
plt.hold(True)
plt.plot(pred_upd)
plt.show()
```

You can put some parameters in there - but that should be the format.